# Multiple Bluetooth Antennas?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I plan on conducting an arts display that heavily uses bluetooth.

On the recommendation of one of my friends, the suggested having a regular USB Bluetooth antenna (Ceiling Mounted) on an extension cable far away from the computer to get close to the performance so that the audience's Bluetooth devices won't cause interference.

What if I had multiple Bluetooth antennas (My notebook already has a Bluetooth antenna as a part of its WLAN module).

Would the Bluetooth device find the antenna with the best connection at the time or would it just pair to one and stick with that one antenna? What would happen if it lost the signal? Would it try and find the same antenna, or any antenna it could get? Is the overall signal more fail-safe with multiple antennas, or should I disable my WLAN based Bluetooth antenna to maximize the chance that the signal is not lost?

Comment: Bluetooth peripherals are generally designed to be paired to exactly one Bluetooth host controller at a time. They don't roam/handoff between different host controllers.

Comment: Try to do this could easily result in lost or screwed up pairings. This is more suited to Wi-Fi - can you do it by Wi-Fi?

Comment: Later generations of BT (4.1 and up) can pair more than one device.

Comment: @John I'm using a Neurosky Mindwave Mobile EEG reader. It only lists Bluetooth as a protocol for output.

Comment: Can you consider wireless for this setup?

Comment: @John I don't understand. Bluetooth is a wireless protocol that is used by the Mindwave Mobile. Do you mean wi-fi?

Comment: Wi-Fi is just standard wireless. You would need a wireless router to support it, but it should be easy to set up

Comment: @John Wait... I'm confused, are you saying that a wireless router can convert the Bluetooth coming off the EEG to a Wi-Fi signal?

Comment: Bluetooth is short range and pairs. So I do not know how you can do that with multiple devices. Using Wireless to broadcast a signal was just a suggestion.

Comment: Also (apologies here): I did not mean converting Bluetooth to wireless, rather replace Bluetooth with wireless.

Comment: @John That's ok, but I don't understand how I could do that given that the hardware only supports Bluetooth connection.